# Trello Default List Label(s)

Tags: trello, trello-lists, trello-labels

In Trello, is there a way to set a default label for every card created in a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to set a default label for cards created in a list. You might try the keyboard shortcuts to add them quickly, though. https://trello.com/shortcuts

Comment: good enough, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one "way": you can create a board named "Template" in your personal or organization board, and copy it for every new board. Then you only have to modify it.